# Объединить два массива в один, с не общими элементами без повтора

Tags: c++

Необходимо два массива объединить в один и оставить в нем только не общие элементы. Например arr1 {1,2,3,4} + arr2{1,1,5,6}, результат arr3 {3,4,6}.

```
const int SIZE1 = 8;
const int SIZE2 = 5;
int arr1[SIZE1] = { 0 };
int arr2[SIZE2] = { 0 };
cout << "First array\n";
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++){
    arr1[i] = rand() % 20;
    cout << arr1[i] << '\t';
}

cout << "\nSecond array\n";
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++){
    arr2[i] = rand() % 20;
    cout << arr2[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
const int SIZE3 = SIZE1 + SIZE2;
int arr3[SIZE3] = { 0 };
cout << "Third array\n";
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE3; i++){
    arr3[i] = arr1[i];
    if (i >= SIZE1)
        arr3[i] = arr2[i-SIZE1];
    cout << arr3[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
const int SIZE4 = SIZE3;
int arr4[SIZE4] = { 0 };
int size4 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE4; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE4; j++){
        if (arr3[i] == arr3[j]&&i!=j)
            break;
        else if (arr3[i] != arr3[j]&&j<SIZE4-1)
            continue;
        else if (arr3[i] != arr3[SIZE4-1]&&j==SIZE4-1)
        {
            arr4[size4] = arr3[i];
            size4++;
        }
    }
}
cout << "Sorted array\n";
for (int i = 0; i < size4; i++){
    cout << arr4[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: Вообще-то в C++ для этого предназначен [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: @PinkTux нет, std::set_symmetric_difference()

Comment: @gbg, ну да, давно я в школе не был :)

Comment: Поразмыслив еще, я решила просто объединить два массива в третий. А потом сделать проверку на неравенство элементов И записать новые значения в 4-й массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вот, решение которое я реализовала:

```
const int SIZE1 = 5;
const int SIZE2 = 7;
int arr1[SIZE1] = { 0 };
int arr2[SIZE2] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
    cout << (arr1[i] = rand() % 10) << "\t";
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++)
    cout << (arr2[i] = rand() % 10) << "\t";
cout << endl;



const int SIZE3 = SIZE2+SIZE1;

int arr3[SIZE3] = { 0 };
int size3 = 0;
//сравниваем 1 со вторым, разницу записыв в 3
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (arr1[i] != arr2[j]) {
            bool exist = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < size3; k++) {
                if (arr1[i] == arr3[k]) {
                    exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (exist == false&&j==SIZE2-1) {
                arr3[size3] = arr1[i];
                size3++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//сравниваем 2 массив  с первым, разницу записываем в 3 с места где закончилась запись сравнения 1 и 2
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE1; j++) {
        if (arr2[i] == arr1[j])
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (arr2[i] != arr1[j]) {
            bool exist = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < size3; k++) {
                if (arr2[i] == arr3[size3-k]) {
                    exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (exist == false && j == SIZE1 - 1) {
                arr3[size3] = arr2[i];
                size3++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


cout << "Array 3\n";
for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
    cout << arr3[i] << "\t";
}
```

Всем участника спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 7):

В `C++` весь нужный функционал уже есть, надо только им воспользоваться.

Искомое называется "Симметрическая разность множеств".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::set;
using std::vector;
using std::set_symmetric_difference;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::cout;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> first={7,1,1,2,3};
    vector<int> second={6,1,2,5,6,7};
    
    const set<int> alpha(begin(first),end(first));
    const set<int> beta(begin(second),end(second));
        
    ostream_iterator<int> out(cout,", ");
    
    set_symmetric_difference(begin(alpha),end(alpha),begin(beta),end(beta),out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/XI19ay)

Сперва мы задаем наши массивы `first` и `second`.

Затем, конвертируем во множество - `std::set`

Затем, находим разность и сразу выдаем на терминал;

## Послесловие

Я прекрасно понимаю, что это "учебная" задача, нацеленная на изобретение велосипеда, но. Такая задача к практике не готовит никак. Потому как в реальности, все вакансии программиста `C++` требуют знания STL. А наше дурное образование STL игнорирует.

Comment: *А наше дурное образование STL игнорирует* Я бы сформулировал иначе. Если готовить кодера-ремесленника, да, ему просто надо давать готовые решения и бить по рукам за попытки **понимать**. Но чтобы человек **понимал** STL, он должен во время учебы не просто ехать на велосипеде, но и изобрести его - только так он поймет, что и как работает, и когда и что следует применять. Изобретение велосипеда под руководством учителя - очень неплохой подход. IMHO, конечно. Вы красиво и эффективно, и даже эффектно решили задачу, но главное - научить - осталось за рамками... :(

Comment: @Harry нужно просто органично встроить STL в учебный процесс. В математике, почему-то, студентов не заставляют самостоятельно передоказывать весь матанализ, а тут - пожалуйста.

Comment: *А наше дурное образование STL игнорирует* - наше образование инертно до ужаса. Методички не просто прошлого века, а прошлого века с хвостиком, это нормально. И хрен там шаг вправо-шаг влево. Не говоря уж о том, что доцент, который тащит на себе десяток-другой студентов, и получающий со всеми компенсациями тыщ 20... Д кому это упало...

Comment: @gbg ну я бы поспорил, я из курса МатАнализа помню доказательства основных теорем...

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если задание учебное, **и вас все равно устраивает эффективность `O(n*m)`**, то можно сделать так - при сравнении сразу добавлять в выходной массив:

```
bool search(int value, int * begin, int * end)
{
    for(;begin != end; ++begin)
        if(*begin == value) return true;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand(time(nullptr));

    const int SIZE1 = 10;
    const int SIZE2 = 5;
    int arr1[SIZE1] = { 0 };
    int arr2[SIZE2] = { 0 };
    int arr [SIZE1+SIZE2] = { 0 };
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
        cout << (arr1[i] = rand() % 15) << "\t";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++)
        cout << (arr2[i] = rand() % 15) << "\t";
    cout << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
    {
        if (search(arr1[i],arr2,arr2+SIZE2)) continue;
        arr[size++] = arr1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++)
    {
        if (search(arr2[i],arr1,arr1+SIZE1)) continue;
        arr[size++] = arr2[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    cout << endl;


}
```

Правда, так мы не убираем дубли в одном массиве (но если они допустимы во входном, почему их не должно быть в выходном?) - но это просто, надо только добавить в циклы `search` еще и по выходному массиву.

Comment: Короткая рецензия:
1. Плохой способ создания ограниченного набора случайных чисел - взятие остатка дает неравномерное распределение. Потом стюдент это скопипастит туда, где это важно и будет конфуз. Есть uniform_int_distribution
2. Ни о чем не говорящие названия переменных. Стюдент и такой подход скопипастит. А гипотетические коллеги потом учинят матомный взрыв.

Comment: @gbg Я просто повторил заполнение автором вопроса, так как в вопросе о способе заполнения не было ни слова :) Думаю, что как раз в учебном задании, там, где человек решает простейшую задачу и у него мало что получается, применение того же `uniform...` только покажет, что этот код просто списан :) Подвизаясь время от времени на Reshaem.net, я стараюсь всегда учитывать уровень студента, и это себя оправдывает. Я бы скорее менял сам алгоритмический подход, но опять же - важно не столько эффективно и красиво решить задачу, а помочь студенту **понять**, как это делается.

Comment: увы, это попустительство. С таким подходом лично вы конечно получите выгоду от образовательного процесса, но уровень студента будет только деградировать, так как стимул к росту будет отсутствовать.

Comment: @gbg Деградация будет при подходе "возьми готовое и не лезь внутрь - умные дяди все решили за тебя". Я говорил о том, что у каждого есть свой уровень **понимания**, и когда я решаю задачу на уровне понимания студента - я знаю, что он не просто пойдет и отдаст преподу, а **поймет**, что он отдает. При вашем подходе студент либо пролетит, не сумев объяснить, как решена задача, либо препод молча примет решение, прекрасно понимая, откуда оно взялось. Я за то, чтоб блондинка за рулем понимала, **как** ездит машина, а не просто крутила руль.

Comment: только вот "понимание" студент обретает не самостоятельно, а с поддержкой. В итоге, самостоятельно решать свои проблемы он так и не научится, а то, что ему нажевали, вылетит из его головы через 15 минут. "Сдал - забыл".

Comment: @gbg Интересно бы узнать мнение самого автора вопроса :) Anastasiia Melnyk, откликнитесь! :)

Comment: Для меня главное не только понять работу программы, но и через несколько занятий суметь использовать подход решения на другой задаче без заминок. Соглашусь с @gbg, что объяснять лучше на уровне ученика. А чтобы не было деградации, при объяснении надо направлять на решение, а не давать готовый код. К сожалению, я еще не знакома с STL, функциями и указателями. Я понимаю, что для такой задачи мой код сильно большой, но для меня сейчас главное решить ее. А оптимизацией кода можно будет заняться чуть позже.

Comment: @AnastasiiaMelnyk, простейшей оптимизацией будет отсортировать массивы и использовать двоичный поиск для определения, есть ли данный элемент в другом массиве. Следующим шагом можно уменьшить количество поисков в первом массиве при просмотре второго (достаточно помечать в нем уже обнаруженные общие элементы (вероятно, для этого придется создать вспомогательный *битовый* массив)).